# Joomla simple text area that send data via POST

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm developing my Joomla! 2.5 Component.

It, with an username && password passed via admin area, could connect to a webserver that send info via XML.

I can show this component in any part of front-end without problem.

Now i need to insert, in frontend for end-user, a single text-area where users could insert a value (e.g., theyr card number [it's a loyalty component]) and this value must be passed to previous component.

ATM I don't need AJAX call, page could be refreshed.

So process it must textarea => insert data => press submit => show component with result (page refresh, no problem).

I need to develop a plugin? I need to "extend" component? Saw several topic on web but i didn't  found any that show a (i think) simple case like my.

I need a hand from you, to be on correct way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main controller file you can access the post & get values, so

Where you want to place the input: Just create a form that points to your component, with appropriate

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_yourcomp" method="get"
  <input type="text" name="your_text_input"...
```

Add all extra fields that you need.

In the controller.php of the com_yourcomp you will be able to access the user data with

JRequest::getVar('your_text_input') or jInput as you prefer.

Note on method="get": you do so if you want your users to be able to bookmark the page or you plan a redirect in your component.  The user inputs must be limited to a few thousand chars at most.  Otherwise use post, it really depends on your needs.